# How to change python error language in terminal?

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal

I have ubuntu 16.04 and in my native language I started to get errors like

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: ������������:  INSERT ������ UPDATE �� �������������� "m2m_cities_regions" ���������������� ���������������������� ���������������� ���������� "m2m_cities_regions_regions_id_660c0306_fk_regions_id" 
DETAIL:  �������� (regions_id)=(190354225) ���������������������� �� �������������� "regions".` in terminal.

It is not so easy to fix localization as I thought. As a workaround I want to change error language. I remember that abound 6 months ago all errors were in English, but after some update this was changed. Could anyone tell me how can I push python to show me all errors in English?

Added screeshot:
[image]

Comment: What is your database backend?

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov PostgreSQL 9.5

Comment: Always worth a shot, have you tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`? Might help with the non-display chars

Comment: @kpie you mean screenshot? Added. Comands you mentioned already tried - nothing changed. Also tried dpkg-reconfigure locales. I changed the OS interface to English, but error still has '????'

Comment: @TitanFighter The problem isn't localization. The script you are attempting to use contains or is generating non-ascii characters. The error itself is in english.

Comment: @Natecat, If I print() all content, everything is readable. Does it make any sense? If it is not irrelevant, could you advise me anything to make it readable in this particular case? The content in russian.

Comment: @TitanFighter I'm fairly sure the only error that really matters is the very top one. Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by the first part.

Comment: There is a layer of translation between the json you see and the bson that django stores.

Comment: @Natecat, I meant, if I use print() function, to print all text that the script handles, the text is readable

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov your answer was almost correct. I tried to `SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';` but it didnt help. I was needed to change `lc_messages` manually in config file. So you can post your answer again and I'll accept it. The error was: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "m2m_cities_regions" violates foreign key constraint "m2m_cities_regions_regions_id_660c0306_fk_regions_id"
DETAIL:  Key (regions_id)=(190354225) is not present in table "regions".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem on your database backend side. Django don't translate these messages.

In unix-based systems you need to execute this:

```
SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

In windows set [environment variable](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/create-custom-environment-variables-in-windows-7/) `LC_MESSAGES` to `English`. And then restart the server.